# Show that the map $B\mapsto A^tB+B^tA$ is not surjective if $A$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, positive-definite

> Let $M(n,\mathbb R)$ and $\mbox{Sym} (n,\mathbb R)$ denote the set of $n \times n$ real matrices and the set of $n\times n$ real *symmetric* matrices, respectively. Suppose $f : M (n,\mathbb R) \to \mbox{Sym} (n,\mathbb R)$ is a map defined by $$f(B):=A^tB+B^tA$$ where $A$ is a given singular $n \times n$ matrix. Show that $f$ is not surjective if $A$ is singular.

I have already proved the converse of the statement, but not sure about this direction yet.

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: If $A$ is singular it has a non-trivial nullspace. Can you see why that's relevant?

Comment: @CyclotomicField: Then there exists $x\neq 0$ s.t. $Ax=0$, so $f(B)x=A^tBx$ for any $B$. Could you provide a bit more hints?

Comment: *Hint.* Some symmetric matrices $P$ are positive definite (e.g. $P=I$), so that $x^tPx>0$ for every nonzero vector $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Following the hints provided by [CyclotomicField](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538130/show-that-the-map-b-mapsto-atbbta-is-not-surjective-if-a-is-singular#comment9540475_4538130) and [user11551](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538130/show-that-the-map-b-mapsto-atbbta-is-not-surjective-if-a-is-singular#comment9540522_4538130))

If $A$ is singular, then there exists some $x_0\neq 0$ such that $Ax_0=0$.
Suppose $f$ is surjective. Let $P$ be a positive definite matrix, that is, $x^tPx>0$ for every non-zero vector $x$. There exists a matrix $B$ such that $f(B)=P$. It follows that $x_0^tPx_0=x_0^t(A^tB+B^tA)x_0=x_0^tA^tBx_0=(Ax_0)^tBx_0=0$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure of this, but here's a proof sketch: Suppose $x\neq 0$ is such that $Ax=0$. Let $y\neq 0$. We have that $f(B)x=A^tBx+B^tAx=A^tBx$. Now consider $z=A^tBx+y\neq A^tBx$. We can always rotate space to bring $x$ along $z$ and then scale it appropriately - this is a product of a rotation and a scaling, so I claim there must exist a symmetric matrix $C$ such that $Cx=z$. But there is no choice of $B$ for which $f(B)=C$. Hence, $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Your claim is indeed correct. But I don't quite understand why 'there is no choice of $B$ for which $f(B)=C$', as you didn't choose $B$ in the first place (thus your $z$ and $C$ depends on the arbitrary $B$). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Will it be okay to say that for any $B$, we can find a $C$ such that $f(B)\neq C$?